# Laravel:A table have no relationship with another table

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update record in "Events" Table but "Events" Table have no relationship with another Table
Then what should i do in Models

Here is my code and explanation

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ route('events.edit',$event->id)}}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

I'm sending the $event->id to the edit.blade.php page for edit request

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('events.update',$event->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  {{csrf_field()}}

  {{method_field('PATCH')}}

  <div class="box-body">

    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <div class="box-body">

    <div class="col-lg-6">

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Event Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title"
        value="{{$event->title}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subtitle">Place</label>
      <input type="text" name="place" class="form-control" id="place" placeholder="Place the Destination"
     value="{{$event->place}}" >
    </div>
```

And this form is receiving the $event->id request but when i run this code this error is occur

"Undefined variable: event (View: F:\society\resources\views\admin\events\edit.blade.php)"

Here is the Event Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $events = event::where('id',$id)->first();
    return view('admin.events.edit',compact('events'));
}
```

And update function is here

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $this->validate($request,[

        'title'=>'required',
        'place'=>'required',
        'starttime'=>'required',
        'endtime'=>'required',
        'datepicker'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required',
        'image'=>'required'

    ]);
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $img = $request->file('image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($img)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

    }

    $event=event::find($id);
    $event->image= $filename;
    $event->title =$request->title;
    $event->place =$request->place;
    $event->starttime =$request->starttime;
    $event->endtime =$request->endtime;
    $event->datepicker =$request->datepicker;
    $event->body =$request->body;
    $event->save();
    return redirect(route('events.index'));
}
```

And Model is here

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(event::class);
    }
}
```

Please tell me where is the problem
Problem in Model or somewhere else

Comment: You're passing `$events` in your compact function, but using `$event` in your blade. As an aside, you can shorten your model retrieving with `find()`, since you're getting it by ID: `$event = event::find($id);`

Comment: You're using events in controller but event in blade template~!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 2):

Your controller code should look something like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $event = event::findOrFail($id)
    return view('admin.events.edit', compact('event'));
}
```

You were passing the variable `events` instead of `event`

Comment: Thanks a lot mate 

Comment: hey could you please accept this as the correct answer :) thanks!